# How to check, whether the subform is valid

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, symfony-forms

In my form builder, I add the sub form

```
->add('bankAccount', BankAccountFormType::class, [
])
```

How can I say to validate the subform only for certain validation groups?
Something like this:

```
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'groups' => [
                        Person::TYPE_CUSTOMER, Person::TYPE_WITNESS, Person::TYPE_INSURED_PERSON
                    ]
                ])
            ]
```

Which constraint should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that VALID will useful for you just read here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Comment: it also doesn't work

->add('bankAccount', BankAccountFormType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Valid([
                        'groups' => [
                            Person::TYPE_CUSTOMER
                        ]
                    ])
                ],

            ])

should I define the validation group in each field of the BankAccountFormType?